# Ruby on Rails: instance & class variables not maintaining value in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

at the top of my controller, outside of any method, I have

```
    @@javascript_is_disabled = false
```

and I have methods that that the view calls and invokes something like this

```
    @@javascript_is_disabled = params[:javascript_disabled]
```

but when I need the @@javascript_is_disabled in completely different method.. it is always false.

I know it changes in the method with params args... cause those methods behave differently, and appropriately

And ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `@@javascript_is_disabled` is a **class variable** and it refers to a different thing depending on where you access it from. From within the Controller class body it doesn't refer to the same thing as when you use it from within a controller method or a view.  This is actually a pretty complex subject involving [Eigenclasses](http://www.klankboomklang.com/2007/10/05/the-metaclass/)

I suggest implementing it using a view helper or a protected method:

```
protected

attr_writer :javascript_is_disabled
def javascript_is_disabled
  # Replace false with your intended default value
  @javascript_is_disabled.nil? ? false : @javascript_is_disabled
end
```

Then you can reference it from within your views and controller action methods like an attribute `javascript_is_disabled = true`  or `if javascript_is_disabled ...`

You could also leave out the `attr_writer ...` part and just always remember to assign values to the instance variable `@javascript_is_disabled = ...`